# How do I run code in a thread that called a parameterless Application.Run()?

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I want to render a chart with the [DevExpress ChartControl](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraChartsChartControltopic) via the WiForm [DrawToBitmap()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) function on a separate thread.

I try something like:

```
Form yourForm;
Thread thread = new Thread( () =>
{
     yourForm = new HiddenForm();
     Application.Run(yourForm);
});
thread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
thread.Start();
yourForm.Invoke(chartRenderingFunction)
```

And simple make sure the Hidden never actually gets displayed. However, I don't need that hidden form, and there is a parameterless form of [Application.Run()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900.aspx). However, if I run that, it doesn't return. So my question is once I call Application.Run() inside a thread, how do I inject code in it?

Comment: What are you trying to achive? I dont understand the purpes of HiddenForm?

Comment: @JensKloster My chart takes a long time (seconds) to render. If I render it to an image on the main thread the window is non-responsive during those seconds. That is not a good user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you actually really do need that hidden window.  The only way to get code to run on that thread.  Somebody must call PostMessage() and that requires a window handle.  Your Invoke() call makes that call.  You really should use BeginInvoke() instead, there's no point in starting a thread if you are going to wait for the call to complete.

Using Application.Run(yourForm) is going to make the window visible.  You can stop it from becoming visible by overriding the SetVisibleCore() method in your HiddenForm class:

```
protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value) {
    if (!this.IsHandleCreated) {
        CreateHandle();
        value = false;
        ThreadReady.Set();
    }
    base.SetVisibleCore(value);
}
```

The CreateHandle() call is necessary to make sure that the window is created so it can process the PostMessage() notifications.  Also note the added AutoResetEvent (ThreadReady), you are going to have to call ThreadReady.WaitOne() after calling the thread's Start() method to ensure that your BeginInvoke() call is going to work.  Dispose the form to get the thread to exit or call Application.Exit().

Last but not least, be **very** careful with using non-trivial controls on that thread.  A chart control certainly is not indicated.  You'll have long-lasting problems if that control uses the SystemEvents class for example.  Your worker thread will get it to raise events on that worker thread.  But it won't be around anymore after the chart is printed.  You'll now get the events fired on an arbitrary threadpool thread, very nasty.  A deadlock is a common mishap, particularly apt to trigger when locking the workstation.

Comment: Regarding the events, what if I dispose my control after it renders the image? Will any events fire at that point? If that is not the case, can't I just let this message pump thread live the entire life of the process? I'm ok with that.

Comment: The SystemEvents mishap is not affected by whether you leave the thread running or not, it will still be fired on the wrong thread as far as the rest of your UI windows go when you keep it alive.  I'm not promising trouble, just warning you about it.

Comment: I'm a little confused, and probably ignorant of something. I just want to call [Control.DrawToBitmap()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) on the control, and then dispose the control. System.Drawing.Bitmap does not actually interact with the message pump at all. Its holds the image data in a device independent way (or so says every GDI description). Am I in danger if a systemevent is raised (1) for the short lifetime of the ChartControl or (2) during the lifetime of the bitmap object?

Comment: The Chart control should be your concern, not Bitmap.  Controls always have a good reason to use SystemEvents, particularly for the UserPreferenceChanged event.  I don't know if it does, I don't use DevExpress controls.

Comment: What is ThreadReady.Set()? ReSharper doesn't resolve it, and google doesn't find it. I'm using .net 4.0 VS 2010.

Comment: That's the AutoResetEvent variable that you need to add to your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39297/discussion-between-justin-dearing-and-hans-passant)